# FCFS CPU Scheduling program in C++

Tags: c++, cpu, scheduling

I am trying to implement the FCFS CPU scheduling in c++. I have the following code which runs error free but gives me "Rubbish data" on some of the numbers such as the values of the Waiting time, response time and turn around time for all of the processes except the first one calculated

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class ProcessInfo
{
public:
    string ProcessID;
    int BurstTime;
    int Arrival;

    int WaitingTime;
    int ResponseTime;
    int TurnaroundTime;
};

int main()
{
    ProcessInfo P1, P2, P3 = ProcessInfo();

    ProcessInfo Array[3] = {P1, P2, P3};

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Please enter Process ID for process "<<i<<endl;
        cin>>Array[i].ProcessID;

        cout<<"Please enter Burst Time for process "<<i<<endl;
        cin>>Array[i].BurstTime;

        cout<<"Please enter Arrival Time for process "<<i<<endl;
        cin>>Array[i].Arrival;
    }

    if (Array[0].Arrival < Array[1].Arrival && Array[0].Arrival < Array[2].Arrival)
    {
        if (Array[1].Arrival < Array[2].Arrival)
        {
            P1.WaitingTime = 0;
            P1.ResponseTime = 0;
            P1.TurnaroundTime = P1.BurstTime;

            P2.WaitingTime = P1.TurnaroundTime - (P2.Arrival - P1.Arrival);
            P2.ResponseTime = 0;
            P2.TurnaroundTime = P2.WaitingTime + P2.BurstTime;

            P3.WaitingTime = P2.TurnaroundTime - (P3.Arrival - P2.Arrival);
            P3.ResponseTime = P2.TurnaroundTime - (P3.Arrival - P2.Arrival) ;
            P3.TurnaroundTime = P3.WaitingTime + P3.BurstTime;

            cout<<"Order of processes is: P1, P2, P3"<<endl;

            cout<<"The waiting time for P1: "<< P1.WaitingTime<<endl;
            cout<<"The response time for P1: "<<P1.ResponseTime<<endl;
            cout<<"The Turnaround time for P1: "<<P1.TurnaroundTime<<endl;

            cout<<"The waiting time for P2: "<< P2.WaitingTime<<endl;
            cout<<"The response time for P2: "<<P2.ResponseTime<<endl;
            cout<<"The Turnaround time for P2: "<<P2.TurnaroundTime<<endl;

            cout<<"The waiting time for P3: "<< P3.WaitingTime<<endl;
            cout<<"The response time for P3: "<<P3.ResponseTime<<endl;
            cout<<"The Turnaround time for P3: "<<P3.TurnaroundTime<<endl;
        }
        else
            if (Array[2].Arrival < Array[1].Arrival)
            {
                P1.WaitingTime = 0;
                P1.ResponseTime = 0;
                P1.TurnaroundTime = P1.BurstTime;

                P3.WaitingTime = P1.TurnaroundTime - (P3.Arrival - P1.Arrival);
                P3.ResponseTime = P3.WaitingTime;
                P3.TurnaroundTime = P3.WaitingTime + P3.BurstTime;

                P2.WaitingTime = P3.TurnaroundTime - (P2.Arrival - P3.Arrival);
                P2.ResponseTime = P2.WaitingTime;
                P2.TurnaroundTime = P2.WaitingTime + P2.BurstTime;

                cout<<"Order of processes is: P1, P3, P2"<<endl;

                cout<<"The waiting time for P1: "<< P1.WaitingTime<<endl;
                cout<<"The response time for P1: "<<P1.ResponseTime<<endl;
                cout<<"The Turnaround time for P1: "<<P1.TurnaroundTime<<endl;

                cout<<"The waiting time for P3: "<< P3.WaitingTime<<endl;
                cout<<"The response time for P3: "<<P3.ResponseTime<<endl;
                cout<<"The Turnaround time for P3: "<<P3.TurnaroundTime<<endl;

                cout<<"The waiting time for P2: "<< P2.WaitingTime<<endl;
                cout<<"The response time for P2: "<<P2.ResponseTime<<endl;
                cout<<"The Turnaround time for P2: "<<P2.TurnaroundTime<<endl;
            }
    }

    else
        if(Array[1].Arrival < Array[0].Arrival && Array[1].Arrival < Array[2].Arrival)
        {
            if (Array[2].Arrival < Array[0].Arrival)
            {
                P2.WaitingTime = 0;
                P2.ResponseTime = 0;
                P2.TurnaroundTime = P2.BurstTime;

                P3.WaitingTime = P2.TurnaroundTime - (P3.Arrival - P2.Arrival);
                P3.ResponseTime = P3.WaitingTime;
                P3.TurnaroundTime = P3.WaitingTime + P3.BurstTime;

                P1.WaitingTime = P3.TurnaroundTime - (P1.Arrival - P3.Arrival);
                P1.ResponseTime = P1.WaitingTime;
                P1.TurnaroundTime = P1.WaitingTime + P1.BurstTime;

                cout<<"Order of processes is: P2, P3, P1"<<endl;

                cout<<"The waiting time for P2: "<< P2.WaitingTime<<endl;
                cout<<"The response time for P2: "<<P2.ResponseTime<<endl;
                cout<<"The Turnaround time for P2: "<<P2.TurnaroundTime<<endl;

                cout<<"The waiting time for P3: "<< P3.WaitingTime<<endl;
                cout<<"The response time for P3: "<<P3.ResponseTime<<endl;
                cout<<"The Turnaround time for P3: "<<P3.TurnaroundTime<<endl;

                cout<<"The waiting time for P1: "<< P1.WaitingTime<<endl;
                cout<<"The response time for P1: "<<P1.ResponseTime<<endl;
                cout<<"The Turnaround time for P1: "<<P1.TurnaroundTime<<endl;
            }
            else
                if (Array[0].Arrival < Array[2].Arrival)
                {
                    P2.WaitingTime = 0;
                    P2.ResponseTime = 0;
                    P2.TurnaroundTime = P2.BurstTime;

                    P1.WaitingTime = P2.TurnaroundTime - (P1.Arrival - P2.Arrival);
                    P1.ResponseTime = P1.WaitingTime;
                    P1.TurnaroundTime = P1.WaitingTime + P1.BurstTime;

                    P3.WaitingTime = P1.TurnaroundTime - (P3.Arrival - P1.Arrival);
                    P3.ResponseTime = P3.WaitingTime;
                    P3.TurnaroundTime = P3.WaitingTime + P3.BurstTime;

                    cout<<"Order of processes is: P2, P1, P3"<<endl;

                    cout<<"The waiting time for P2: "<< P2.WaitingTime<<endl;
                    cout<<"The response time for P2: "<<P2.ResponseTime<<endl;
                    cout<<"The Turnaround time for P2: "<<P2.TurnaroundTime<<endl;

                    cout<<"The waiting time for P1: "<< P1.WaitingTime<<endl;
                    cout<<"The response time for P1: "<<P1.ResponseTime<<endl;
                    cout<<"The Turnaround time for P1: "<<P1.TurnaroundTime<<endl;

                    cout<<"The waiting time for P3: "<< P3.WaitingTime<<endl;
                    cout<<"The response time for P3: "<<P3.ResponseTime<<endl;
                    cout<<"The Turnaround time for P3: "<<P3.TurnaroundTime<<endl;

                }
        }
        else

            if(Array[2].Arrival < Array[1].Arrival && Array[2].Arrival < Array[0].Arrival)
            {
                if (Array[1].Arrival < Array[0].Arrival)
                {
                    P3.WaitingTime = 0;
                    P3.ResponseTime = 0;
                    P3.TurnaroundTime = P1.BurstTime;

                    P2.WaitingTime = P3.TurnaroundTime - (P2.Arrival - P3.Arrival);
                    P2.ResponseTime = P2.WaitingTime;
                    P2.TurnaroundTime = P2.WaitingTime + P2.BurstTime;

                    P1.WaitingTime = P2.TurnaroundTime - (P1.Arrival - P2.Arrival);
                    P1.ResponseTime = P1.WaitingTime;
                    P1.TurnaroundTime = P1.WaitingTime + P1.BurstTime;

                    cout<<"Order of processes is: P3, P2, P1"<<endl;

                    cout<<"The waiting time for P3: "<< P3.WaitingTime<<endl;
                    cout<<"The response time for P3: "<<P3.ResponseTime<<endl;
                    cout<<"The Turnaround time for P3: "<<P3.TurnaroundTime<<endl;

                    cout<<"The waiting time for P2: "<< P2.WaitingTime<<endl;
                    cout<<"The response time for P2: "<<P2.ResponseTime<<endl;
                    cout<<"The Turnaround time for P2: "<<P2.TurnaroundTime<<endl;

                    cout<<"The waiting time for P1: "<< P1.WaitingTime<<endl;
                    cout<<"The response time for P1: "<<P1.ResponseTime<<endl;
                    cout<<"The Turnaround time for P1: "<<P1.TurnaroundTime<<endl;
                }
                else
                    if (Array[0].Arrival < Array[1].Arrival)
                    {
                        P3.WaitingTime = 0;
                        P3.ResponseTime = 0;
                        P3.TurnaroundTime = P1.BurstTime;

                        P1.WaitingTime = P3.TurnaroundTime - (P1.Arrival - P3.Arrival);
                        P1.ResponseTime = P1.WaitingTime;
                        P1.TurnaroundTime = P1.WaitingTime + P1.BurstTime;

                        P2.WaitingTime = P1.TurnaroundTime - (P2.Arrival - P1.Arrival);
                        P2.ResponseTime = P2.WaitingTime;
                        P2.TurnaroundTime = P2.WaitingTime + P2.BurstTime;

                        cout<<"Order of processes is: P3, P1, P2"<<endl;

                        cout<<"The waiting time for P3: "<< P3.WaitingTime<<endl;
                        cout<<"The response time for P3: "<<P3.ResponseTime<<endl;
                        cout<<"The Turnaround time for P3: "<<P3.TurnaroundTime<<endl;

                        cout<<"The waiting time for P1: "<< P1.WaitingTime<<endl;
                        cout<<"The response time for P1: "<<P1.ResponseTime<<endl;
                        cout<<"The Turnaround time for P1: "<<P1.TurnaroundTime<<endl;

                        cout<<"The waiting time for P2: "<< P2.WaitingTime<<endl;
                        cout<<"The response time for P2: "<<P2.ResponseTime<<endl;
                        cout<<"The Turnaround time for P2: "<<P2.TurnaroundTime<<endl;
                    }
            }



    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use `P1`, `P2` and `P3` for your calculations. Instead use `Array[0]`, `Array[1]` and `Array[2]` for it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't initialize the variable `P1` and `P2`, so the contents of these structure will be undefined.

This will make operations like

```
P1.TurnaroundTime = P1.BurstTime;
```

undefined as well.

If you want good start value, add a default constructor.

Comment: I added the following default constructor

Comment: class ProcessInfo
{
public:
 string ProcessID;
 int BurstTime;
 int Arrival;

 int WaitingTime;
 int ResponseTime;
 int TurnaroundTime;

 ProcessInfo()
 {
  ProcessID = " ";
  BurstTime = 0;
  Arrival = 0;
  WaitingTime = 0;
  ResponseTime = 0;
  TurnaroundTime = 0;
 }

};

Now it gives me Zero's for all the values

Comment: @Scorps You might want to step through the code line by line in a debugger, to see it does what you want and sets the values you want.

Answer (score -3):

```
#include<iostream>

#include<cstdio>

#include<cstdlib>

int process,*q,i,slice,a=0,at2[10],to[10];

void takeprocess()

{

    printf("Enter the total number of process\n");

    scanf("%d",&process);


}


void takecputime()

{

    q=(int*)calloc(process,(sizeof(int)));

for(i=1;i<=process;i++)

{

printf("Enter the CPU burst time for the process P%d : ",i);

   scanf("%d",q+i);

   to[i]=at2[i]=*(q+i);

}

}

void checkfcfs()

{
 int wt1[process];

    for(i=1;i<process;i++)

    {

        a=wt1[i]=*(q+i)+a;

    }

    a=0;

    printf("the waiting time for process P1 is : 0\n");

    for(i=1;i<process;i++)

    {

   a=wt1[i]+a;

        printf("the waiting time for process P%d is : %d\n",i+1,wt1[i]);
    }

    a=a/process;

    printf("the average waiting time for processes are :%d\n",a);

    printf("the sequence of the processes are as follows\n");

    for(i=1;i<=process;i++)

    {

        printf("P%d\n",i);

    }


}

using namespace std;

int main()

{

             takeprocess();

             takecputime();

             checkfcfs();

             return 0;


}
```